# Query works in SQL tools for Visual Studio 2022, but not when the program is running

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I'm writing a query that works in the SQL Tools for Visual Studio, and in SSMS.

This is the query:

```
DECLARE @fecha DATE;
DECLARE @tipocombustible INT;
DECLARE @tipocombustible2 INT;

SET @fecha = '2021-01-26';
SET @tipocombustible = 15101514;
SET @tipocombustible2 = 15101515;

SELECT DISTINCT 
    tbl_vehiculos.idtbl_vehiculos AS ID,
    TRIM (' ' FROM tbl_vehiculos.marca) + ' ' + 
        TRIM(' ' FROM tbl_vehiculos.tipo) + ' ' + 
        TRIM(' ' FROM tbl_vehiculos.modelo) AS 'Vehiculo',
    tbl_vehiculos.placas AS 'Placa',
    tbl_vehiculos.tanque AS 'Capacidad',
    tbl_vehiculos.rendimiento AS 'Kms/Ltr'
FROM
    tbl_vehiculos 
INNER JOIN 
    tbl_facturas ON  bl_facturas.idtbl_tipocombust = tbl_vehiculos.idtbl_tipocombust 
LEFT JOIN 
    tbl_bitacora ON tbl_bitacora.fecha_carga = tbl_facturas.fecha 
                 AND tbl_bitacora.idtbl_vehiculos = tbl_vehiculos.idtbl_vehiculos
WHERE 
    tbl_vehiculos.idtbl_tipocombust = @tipocombustible 
    AND tbl_vehiculos.idtbl_tipocombust2 = @tipocombustible2 
    AND tbl_bitacora.fecha_carga NOT IN (SELECT tbl_bitacora.fecha_carga 
                                         FROM tbl_bitacora 
                                         WHERE tbl_bitacora.fecha_carga = @fecha 
                                           AND tbl_bitacora.idtbl_vehiculos = tbl_vehiculos.idtbl_vehiculos);
```

I'm using `DECLARE` get the data that I'm using. The tables are for "cars", "bills", "logbook".

[This is the result I desire and get in SSMS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XznOZ.png)

The code for the function in C# is this:

```
private void facturasGrid_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (facturasGrid.SelectedRows.Count != 0)
    {
        DataGridViewRow row = this.facturasGrid.SelectedRows[0];

        int combustible1 = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["Clave"].Value);
        int combustible2 = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["Clave"].Value);
        var fecha = Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells["Fecha"].Value).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        textBox7.Text = fecha.ToString();
        actualizar_vehiculos(combustible1, combustible2, fecha);
        dateTimePicker1.Value= Convert.ToDateTime(fecha);
    }
}

private void actualizar_vehiculos (int c1,int c2, string fecha)
{
    try
    {
        string conceptos = "SELECT DISTINCT tbl_vehiculos.idtbl_vehiculos AS ID,\r\nTRIM (' ' FROM tbl_vehiculos.marca)+' '+TRIM(' ' FROM tbl_vehiculos.tipo)+' '+TRIM(' ' FROM tbl_vehiculos.modelo) AS 'Vehiculo', "+
                    "\r\ntbl_vehiculos.placas AS 'Placa', " +
                    "\r\ntbl_vehiculos.tanque AS 'Capacidad'," +
                    "\r\ntbl_vehiculos.rendimiento AS 'Kms/Ltr' " +
                    "\r\nFROM tbl_vehiculos " +
                    "\r\nINNER JOIN tbl_facturas ON tbl_facturas.idtbl_tipocombust=tbl_vehiculos.idtbl_tipocombust " +
                    "\r\nLEFT JOIN tbl_bitacora ON tbl_bitacora.fecha_carga=tbl_facturas.fecha AND tbl_bitacora.idtbl_vehiculos=tbl_vehiculos.idtbl_vehiculos " +
                    "\r\nWHERE tbl_vehiculos.idtbl_tipocombust=@tipocombustible and tbl_vehiculos.idtbl_tipocombust2=@tipocombustible2 AND tbl_bitacora.fecha_carga NOT IN (SELECT tbl_bitacora.fecha_carga FROM tbl_bitacora WHERE tbl_bitacora.fecha_carga=@fecha AND tbl_bitacora.idtbl_vehiculos=tbl_vehiculos.idtbl_vehiculos)";

        using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(conceptos, connection);
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tipocombustible", c1);
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tipocombustible2", c2);
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha", Convert.ToDateTime(fecha));

            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(comando);
            comando.ExecuteScalar();

            DataSet datos = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(datos);

            vehiculosGrid.ReadOnly = true;
            vehiculosGrid.DataSource = datos.Tables[0];
            vehiculosGrid.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
            vehiculosGrid.Columns[1].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
            vehiculosGrid.Columns[2].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
            vehiculosGrid.Columns[3].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
            vehiculosGrid.Columns[4].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
            textBox7.Text = vehiculosGrid.RowCount.ToString();

            // Now that DataGridView has calculated it's Widths; we can now store each column Width values.
            for (int i = 0; i <= vehiculosGrid.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                // Store Auto Sized Widths:
                int colw = vehiculosGrid.Columns[i].Width;

                // Remove AutoSizing:
                vehiculosGrid.Columns[i].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None;

                // Set Width to calculated AutoSize value:
                vehiculosGrid.Columns[i].Width = colw;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

When running the query from SSMS, I get the results I want, but when running from C#, I get a blank datagridview with the column header names.

I tried to pinpoint the error by looking to convert the "fecha" string to `Date` SQL Server type and `AddWithValue` to the parameter. The query should fill the gridview with data from [tag:tbl_vehiculos] except those ones that are already in the [tag:tbl_bitacora] table in the date and has the id of the car.

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

**UPDATE:** I had comment the grid manipulation since is just for form's aestetic.

Thank you for helping me, still have the same problem after implementing your suggestions, it does'nt generate any exception, just a blank gridview.

[Winform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLr3O.png)

Then, there is some way that VS is treating the query that is different from the sql tool or the SSMS?

Maybe is returning null values? But why in the SSMS or SqlTool works fine and here it doesn't?

**UPDATE 2:** After a lot, i did change the query, used NOT EXISTS instead of NOT IN. But what really give me the answer was in the Query, the diference was changing the AND to an OR in here:

```
private DataSet actualizar_vehiculos(int c1, int c2, DateTime fecha)
    {
        string conceptos = @"
SELECT DISTINCT v.idtbl_vehiculos AS ID,
    TRIM (' ' FROM v.marca)+' '+TRIM(' ' FROM v.tipo)+' '+TRIM(' ' FROM v.modelo) AS 'Vehiculo',
    v.placas AS 'Placa', 
    v.tanque AS 'Capacidad',
    v.rendimiento AS 'Kms/Ltr' 
FROM tbl_vehiculos v
INNER JOIN tbl_facturas f ON f.idtbl_tipocombust=v.idtbl_tipocombust 
LEFT JOIN tbl_bitacora b ON b.fecha_carga=f.fecha 
     AND b.idtbl_vehiculos=v.idtbl_vehiculos 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
           SELECT fecha_carga 
           FROM tbl_bitacora 
           WHERE fecha_carga=@fecha 
               AND idtbl_vehiculos=v.idtbl_vehiculos
    ) AND v.idtbl_tipocombust=@tipocombustible 
    OR v.idtbl_tipocombust2=@tipocombustible2";

        var datos = new DataSet();
        using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (var comando = new SqlCommand(conceptos, connection))
        using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(comando))
        {
            comando.Parameters.Add("@tipocombustible", SqlDbType.Int).Value = c1;
            comando.Parameters.Add("@tipocombustible2", SqlDbType.Int).Value = c2;
            comando.Parameters.Add("@fecha", SqlDbType.Date).Value = fecha;

            adapter.Fill(datos);
        }
        return datos;
    }
```

Thank you so much for your insight and patience @JoelCoehoorn

Comment: Isn't the problem that you use ExecuteScalar? I'm guessing you want some sort of resultset?

Comment: Please don't add your answer to your question - if your answer is substantially different to the one you have accepted, add it as another answer and comment that you added it so show your exact solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the exact error, but the code below does make several improvements, some of which have a chance to resolve the issue.

Specifically, it's possible we missed an error with the newline characters in the SQL literal that were creating odd effects in the query, the `fecha` value somehow ended up with a fractional time portion or other type conversion issue when converted for SQL, the nested `NOT IN()` query had ambiguity over the repeated table name, or the changes to one of the grid properties reset the data source. This code addresses all of those.

One thing that concerns me is the original code seems not to be aware when a value is a DateTime vs a string. Thanks to cultural/internationalization issues, converting between strings and dates is one of the slower and more error-prone things we can do in a computer, and therefore knowing what kind of value we have in which place, along with minimizing conversions between them, is a good and important thing to do.

```
private void facturasGrid_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (facturasGrid.SelectedRows.Count != 0)
    {
        DataGridViewRow row = this.facturasGrid.SelectedRows[0];

        int combustible1 = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["Clave"].Value);
        int combustible2 = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["Clave"].Value);
        var fecha = Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells["Fecha"].Value).Date;

        textBox7.Text = fecha.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        try 
        {
            var datos = actualizar_vehiculos(combustible1, combustible2, fecha);
            // Possible error here I can't test for, if the grid does not have the columns pre-defined.
            vehiculosGrid.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
            vehiculosGrid.Columns[1].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
            vehiculosGrid.Columns[2].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
            vehiculosGrid.Columns[3].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
            vehiculosGrid.Columns[4].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
            vehiculosGrid.DataSource = datos;            
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        vehiculosGrid.ReadOnly = true;
        textBox7.Text = vehiculosGrid.RowCount.ToString();
        dateTimePicker1.Value = fecha
    }
}

// Returns the data. Keep data access SEPARATE from presention work with the winforms controls.
// Also let the higher level code handle the errors.
private DataTable actualizar_vehiculos (int c1,int c2, DateTime fecha)
{
    string conceptos = @"
    SELECT DISTINCT v.idtbl_vehiculos AS ID,
        TRIM (' ' FROM v.marca)+' '+TRIM(' ' FROM v.tipo)+' '+TRIM(' ' FROM v.modelo) AS 'Vehiculo',
        v.placas AS 'Placa', 
        v.tanque AS 'Capacidad',
        v.rendimiento AS 'Kms/Ltr' 
    FROM tbl_vehiculos v
    INNER JOIN tbl_facturas f ON f.idtbl_tipocombust=v.idtbl_tipocombust 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_bitacora b ON b.fecha_carga=f.fecha 
         AND b.idtbl_vehiculos=v.idtbl_vehiculos 
    WHERE v.idtbl_tipocombust=@tipocombustible 
        and v.idtbl_tipocombust2=@tipocombustible2 
        AND b.fecha_carga NOT IN (
               SELECT fecha_carga 
               FROM tbl_bitacora 
               WHERE fecha_carga=@fecha 
                   AND idtbl_vehiculos=v.idtbl_vehiculos
        )";

    var datos = new DataTable();
    using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (var comando = new SqlCommand(conceptos, connection))
    using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(comando))
    {
        comando.Parameters.Add("@tipocombustible", SqlDbType.Int).Value = c1;
        comando.Parameters.Add("@tipocombustible2", SqlDbType.Int).Value = c2;
        comando.Parameters.Add("@fecha", SqlDbType.Date).Value = fecha;
        
        adapter.Fill(datos);
    }
    return datos;
}
```

One possible remaining error is SQL Tools for Visual Studio is connecting with a different connection string information than the code, or that the result is assigned to the wrong grid.

Comment: i tried removing the NOT IN (SELECT fecha_carga FROM tbl_bitacora               WHERE fecha_carga=@fecha AND idtbl_vehiculos=v.idtbl_vehiculos), and goes back to populate the grid that i want, but doesn't solve my problem, which sql function do you recommend?